# OpenWeatherMap REST API is returning always HTTP 301

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection, openweathermap

I'm trying to process JSON data from an API (`http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk`) but instead I get this on my logcat window: `301 Moved Permanently`

Here is my Class:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                int data = reader.read();

                while (data != -1) {
                    char current = (char) data;
                    result += current;
                    data = reader.read();
                }

                return result;


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Log.i("JSON",s);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
        task.execute("http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to open the url in a browser? I've tried with postman and it works. Maybe is there a problem in your local network?

Comment: Yeah I tried and I get response

Comment: an http 301 means the url you are calling is "old" and has been moved to another url. This means you should follow the new url, that is passed through the headers in the response. Try to read the http headers and look for more information.

Comment: @Yusef Maali, i tried a different link and I got response.I dont know why ):

Comment: please, check the answers, you'll find all the details

Answer (score 1):

Have you given android studio permission to use the INTERNET in the AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Yes I did, but i still can't fetch data

Comment: why aren't you using retrofit or a similar library for the network call? it seems redundant to use an HTTP connection now unless it's specifically needed

Comment: Maybe I'll check on that later

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) (give it a try) to analyze what happens.

The url you provided is: `http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02`.
Reading the response, this is what you will found:

Body:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="white">
    <center>
        <h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1>
    </center>
    <hr>
    <center>openresty/1.9.7.1</center>
</body>

</html>
```

Raw HTML response:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: openresty/1.9.7.1
Date: Sun, 07 Jun 2020 10:49:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 190
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02
```

As said in the comments, when you get an `HTTP 30x` (see: [Redirection messages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)) the server is telling you the url you are calling is old. If you want a correct response you should follow (so the "redirect" message) the new url the server is passing you in the http headers.

The http header you are looking for is `Location`, that is reporting this url:

```
https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02
```

Going through a little diff with the two urls, the server is telling you to call the `https` flavor of the url.
This is a common practice, please use always `https` urls if available.